# MAX (id) function with MySQli

Tags: mysql, select

How can I use the following statement to return only the record with the maximum **PersonID** from the table?

```
/* Create the prepared statement */
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT Max(PersonID) AS PersonID,familyname,firstname,othernames,gender,CountryID,dateofbirth,nrcno,passportno,address,occupation,village,chief,district,StatusID,imgurl

FROM t_persons")) { 

/* Execute the prepared Statement */
$stmt->execute();

/* Bind results to variables */
$stmt->bind_result($PersonID,$familyname,$firstname,$othernames,$gender,$CountryID,$dateofbirth,$nrcno,$passportno,$address,$occupation,$village,$chief,$district,$StatusID,$img);

/* fetch values */
while ($rows = $stmt->fetch()) {
 // display records in a table
```

Comment: No. Use: `SELECT PersonID, familyname, ... FROM t_persons ORDER BY PersonID DESC LIMIT 1;`

Answer (score -2):

in PostgreSQL you could use use something called "windowing and analytics". this does not exist in MySQL however.
an alternative way would be to use GROUP BY and do ..
`SELECT max(id), person, address, ... FROM tab GROUP BY person, address, ...`
this should work somewhat efficiently if you need it for all. if you need it for jsut one folk you should go for ypercube's answer.

Comment: That query would not work neither on MySQL nor on Postgres for the asked question.